Не работает 301 редирект с без слеша на слэш в файле .htaccess
Проставлен такой редирект в файле рядом с .htaccess под названием .htaccess(redirect slash):
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\&
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^\/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

И оно работает только для малой вложенности типо сайт.ком/продукты, а для сайт.ком/продукты/крупы/гречка не работает.
В самом .htaccess ничего подобного нет. При добавлении этого правила в .htaccess ничего не меняется. В других папках .htaccess нет. Если полностью скопировать .htaccess(redirect slash): в .htaccess, то сайт падает. В чем может быть проблема?
